# How to overwrite whole page with new content with php?

Tags: php, overwrite

I want to clear the other contents and rewrite the whole page with different content.

I have:

Mainpage:

```
<?php
    include("script.php");
?>
//blah blah, some pre-coded content
```

Script.php

```
<?php
if(preg_match('/(?i)msie [1-8]/',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
{
    // code to replace everything that is pre-coded in the mainpage
    // and include the new content
    include("replacement.php");
}
?>
```

My question is, how do I delete all the previous content to overwrite the new one in php?

I am looking for something like this (but using PHP):

```
Javascript:
<script>
document.body.innerHTML = "";
</script>
```

To sum it up:

**What am I looking for?:** How to clear out everything in a page, and rewrite a new content. Using **PHP**

Comment: What do you want to overwrite it with? You already have the solution, what are you having trouble with?

Comment: Did you try with if(preg_match('/(?i)msie [1-8]/',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){/*do stuff*/}else{/* do other stuff*/}

Comment: @putvande I wanted it using PHP

Comment: @GigaByte568 New content without page reload?

Comment: @Su4p yeah. I already have the code with the `else {}` but not on the `if (...){}` side.

Comment: @putvande he wants to do `document.body.innerHTML` without js, but using a php function instead

Comment: Why do I get downvotes? Is there anything wrong with my question???

Comment: @GigaByte568 Yes. Unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @RahilWazir, edited the post. Now, is it clear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to remove an output generated by php:

```
ob_start();         //Start buffering
echo "Old content, will not be shown" ;
ob_end_clean();     //Erase the buffer

echo "New content, will be shown" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not clear the output, you already have, because, you sended it direct to the webserver, and the webserver could have sended it already to the Client.

So, instead of Override, you should only output something, you realy want to output. You can reach this by simple `ìf` and `else` logic.

Also take a look at Output Cache:

http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.ob-start.php

Comment: You are downvoting me why ...? And if my answer is wrong, why @Jari gets upvoted, wich is the same, but shorter with more code?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want

```
ob_start();
echo "Hello world";
if(preg_match('/(?i)msie [1-8]/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){
    ob_clean();
    echo "Hello Kitty";
}
ob_get_contents();
```

But, in my opinion, it would be better to have a switch according to a browser, rather than playing around with output buffering id it's not necessary.